# How to autowire spring bean into EventListener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, autowired

i am searching for a way to create a listener that is also a spring component, however when i try to autowire the entity manager bean, it is always null, what am i doing wrong?

```
@Component
public class TestListener {

    @Autowired
    private TestRepository entityManager;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    void beforeEntityUpdateOrSave(final Entity entity) {
        entityManager.someOperation() // -> NullPointerException, because the bean is "null"
    }
}
```

the Entity class has the listener in the @EntityListeners annotation.

```
@EntityListeners(TestListener.class)
public class Entity
```

Comment: It just came to my mind, that there might be already a "entityManager" bean of type EntityManager, not sure if that will work when you specify the type as TestRepository.
Additionally there are some restrictions what you should not do when working with lifecycle callback methods like @PrePersist, i.e. don't interact with other entities: https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event#implementation_restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Is the class TestRepository annotated with @Repository?

You could try making the field entityManager final. I would also recomend using constructor injection instead. Field injection sometimes leads to strange behaviour.

```
@Component
public class TestListener {

    private final TestRepository entityManager;

    public TestListener(@Autowired TestRepository entityManager){
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    ...

    }
}
```